# MapStruct - Create Mapper 2 objects (simple and complex object)

Tags: java, object, mapstruct

I want to create a 2 objects using mapstruct. 1 is simple POJO but the other is complex POJO that has Java Map-like structure:

Complex object :

```
{
      "property1": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "value": true,
        "valueInfo": {
          "info": "Hello"
        }
      },
      "property2": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "string234",
        "valueInfo": {
          "info": "World"
        }
      }
    }
```

Simple object:

```
{

  "id" : 123,
  "name" : "Jon Doe"

}
```

Comment: What is the source bean?

Comment: can you provide a simple example?